# OCaml map of int keys :: where is the 'simple' int module to use with the Map.Make functor?

Tags: ocaml

I need an OCaml map with keys of type *int* so I am using *Map.Make* to create one. However it seems that the [standard modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/index_modules.html) 'only' provide modules like **Big_int**, **Int32**, **Int64** and **Nativeint** which require conversions. So I have to do things like:

```
module IntMap = Map.Make(Int32) 
let a_map = IntMap.add (Int32.of_int 0) "zero" IntMap.empty ;;
```

... which I would rather avoid or define my own silly **Int** module do deal with simple *int* literals or values without requiring conversion functions:

```
module Int = struct                       
   type t = int                                              
   let compare x y = if x < y then -1 else if x > y then 1 else 0 end ;;  
module IntMap = Map.Make(Int) 
let a_map = IntMap.add 0 "zero" IntMap.empty ;;
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Just use `Pervasives.compare`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simplest way to have an int map is to do the following:

```
module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)
```

Comment: You would probably prefer to add a type annotation to the compare function for efficiency reasons:

inline `module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare : int -> int -> int = compare end)`

Comment: @PierreChambart Do you have a use-case where this makes a difference ? Both generated lambda codes looks similar to me.

Comment: Effectively, I don't know why, but I can't get the compiler to specialise compare as compare_int in this case.

Comment: In ocamlc version 3.11.2 the line: `module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)` fails with "**Syntax error: ')' expected, the highlighted '(' might be unmatched**" at the toplevel (similar error message at the ocamlc -c invocation)

Comment: This error can happen in the toplevel in the tuareg mode (because of a bug in the tuareg mode), but should normally compile fine with 3.11.2 (but I haven't tested it). You can stil do: `module Int = struct type t = int let compare = compare end` and `module IntMap = Map.Make(Int)`

Answer (score 7):

I dont think you're missing anything, there's no standard module for this.  I believe the
[BatInt](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatInt.html) module of [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) does what you want.

(Edited to add: it's true, I myself use the method suggested by Thomas!)

Answer (score 2):

You can build `IntMap` [with a one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132568). If you don't mind using third-party libraries, [Jean-Christophe Filliâtre's Patricia tree library](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/software.en.html) (`Ptmap`) is a little more efficient (and similarly `Ptset` for sets of OCaml integers).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use `containers` already (which I think is a bit more commonplace since previous answers were written), you can conveniently use the containers 'primitive' modules along with the CCMap module to achieve this, e.g.:

`module ByInt = CCMap.Make(CCInt)`

Answer (score 0):

As of OCaml 4.08 (released June, 2019) the standard library incldue the [`Int` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Int.html) which fulfills this need.